# Deleting from database resulting in Multiple Endpoints Error

Tags: c#

I am working on a C# E-commerce Application.

After I add two products to my shopping cart, I get Multiple Endpoints error when attempting to delete from the cart.

How can I succesfully delete these items?
Please view the two images attached below.

[Delete From Cart Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpRq2.png)

[Internal Server error when deleting from cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTOIP.png)

Comment: Looks like some problem with the routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two endpoit with same httpmethods(delete) and same parameter(onlineshop) ,you need to be unique route to avoid route conflicts.

```
[HttpDelete("remove")]
public IActionResult Remove(OnlineShop model)
{ 
}
[HttpDelete("removeToChart")]
public IActionResult RemoveToChart(OnlineShop model)
{ 
}
```

Comment: THANKS Masoud. I have added   [ActionName("Remove")].